# Sublimetext "Close Tag" command doesn't work with Django static tags

Tags: django, sublimetext3

For some reason, when I am programming in SublimeText with Python / Django,`%}` tags interfere with Sublime's 'Close Tag' function.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about in practice. It's an `<img>` tag that references a static file within an outer `<div>`. Notice that the `%}` tag is white — Sublime has, for some reason, not recognized it as valid code:

[image]

When I position my cursor at the other end of this line and use the 'Close Tag' command, I would expect sublime to close my `</div>`. Instead, it does this:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a bug with the HTML package in Sublime Text...